# c# print the power of a number using recursion

Tags: c#, recursion, console.writeline

I am learning about recursion and I am required to multiply and do the power of two given numbers. When I run my code it doesn't work (meaning nothing shows on the console)

Methods:

```
 static int multiply (int x, int y)
    {
    if ( y == 1 )
        return   x ;
   else
        return (x + multiply(x, y - 1));
     }

    static int power(int x,int y)
    {
        if (y == 0)
            return 0;
        else
            return (x * power(x, y - 1));
    }
```

Main method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        multiply(2, 4);
        power(2, 5);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Anybody have any ideas? I have a feeling im doing something obviously stupid.

Comment: You're never outputting anything..

Comment: Why do you expect something to show on the console?

Comment: `if (y == 0) return 0;` here should be `return 1`

Comment: for multiplication  
if ( y == 0 )
        return  0 ;
   else
if ( y == 1 )
        return  x  ;
   else ...

Answer (score 2):

Output your code to console:

```
Console.WriteLine(multiply(2, 4));
Console.WriteLine(power(2, 5));
```

You may also need to fix the bug on `power`:

```
if (y == 0) return 1; // x⁰ = 1
```

Comment: Oh yes, how stupid of me. Completely overlooked those two bits. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you are not outputting any data to the console so you can see it. The function Console.WriteLine() will write to the console. Console.ReadLine() on the other hand, will continually wait for input from the console, this is to prevent the program from exiting immediately. Your Main method should look more like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int z = multiply(2, 4);
    int p = power(2, 5);
    Console.WriteLine("z : " + z);
    Console.WriteLine("p : " + p);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

You will notice a bug in your power function, but I'll let you debug that once you can see the output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("2*4=" + multiply(2, 4));
        Console.WriteLine("2^5=" + power(2, 5));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```